# Help - cloth track(s) needed...

Tags: cloth, foley, shortfilm

Hi,

is there any kind soul willing to send me a few cloth tracks? I'm not able to record anything good tonight because of nasty noise pollution at my place. I have to finish a short student-ish film. It's not going so well so far and I'm in hurry as always...

Have a good time,
Martin

Comment: http://www.dynamicinterference.com/sfx/

Comment: thank you, unfortunately too expensive for school project without budget, sounds great though!

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a pinch you could try www.freesound.org.You can find some public domain files there that might help.

Shaun's cloth library is good. @Stavrosound has a link in his comment.

If you are still struggling, take some pink noise, eq it to make it more usable and ride short low bursts of it on larger moves.  It's not ideal but I've used it in the past and it's a patch if there is no other option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Kontakt check [this](http://www.signo-sfx-instruments.com/1st-anniversary-sale/doc_details/332-clothing-bundle-50-off)

Comment: looks great, thanks. i do have kontakt but i've never tried to use it for foleys. good idea.